# Print contents of WebView in Python (Gtk3.0)

Tags: python, printing, webview, gtk3

I have designed a very simple Python3 app that uses a WebView to render Markdown files. 
Now I'd like to add the possibility to print the rendered file (with the current stylesheet that's being applied). I'm desperately trying to find some information about how to do it. Is there any tutorial or howto out there that could explain how to do it?

I've found a few examples explaining how to print PDF files from disk, but I'd like to print things directly from the WebView. Apparently there is even a Method for that but I'm failing miserably on figuring out on how to use it...

See [here](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/WebKit2-4.0/classes/PrintOperation.html)

Best Regards
Merlin

Answer (score 0):

OK, 
I finally figured it out. It appears that only the Webkit2 library is modern enough to handle printing from a Webview. I was using WebKit1 and that was the reason it wouldn't work. So I had to change my dependencies and after that it was actually quite easy...

Lets say that you have a Webview whose name is `myWebView`, then your function to print it's content would look like:

```py
def onPrintButtonClicked( self, widget ):
    #Set the operation up
    printOperation = WebKit2.PrintOperation.new( self.myWebView )
    #Run the dialog
    printOperation.run_dialog()
```

After the dialog, you could actually check if the user has chosen to print or to cancel by checking for `WebKit2.PrintOperationResponse.CANCEL` or `WebKit2.PrintOperationResponse.PRINT` return values.

Reagards